# SQL Server connection string with "$" in password

Tags: powershell, sql-server-2012, connection-string

I have a connection string to a SQL Server 2012 DB:

```
$CONN_STR = "Server=SERVER;Database=mydb;User ID=myuser;Password=abc1$4def;"
```

I'm creating a connection in PowerShell, but the login fails due to invalid password.  I know that the password is correct and validated that in SSMS.   I've tested with another account and from what I can tell, the special character in the password is causing the failure.

How can I escape this in the connection string that I use in PowerShell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this:

```
$CONN_STR = 'Server=SERVER;Database=mydb;User ID=myuser;Password=abc1$4def;'
```

Use single quotes instead that way it wont think you are trying to reference a variable